# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation and CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, scale, cgaffinetransform

How come only one of the above works in code?

Currently I am using the following...

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.5);
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);
```

And my image is scaled to 125% like the second line says, however it is not rotate at all.

When I flip the code around to say...

```
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);
image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.5);
```

My image is rotated but not scaled...

Is there a way to use **both** of these in the same code?

I have these in my `viewDidLoad` method. Can anyone help me?

*Thanks!*

Comment: If you need any more information, comment, and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one should not use the `Make` rendition of the function. Thus you should, for example either:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);
image.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI/2.5);
```

or

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.5);
image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.25, 1.25);
```

Contrast the [Creating an Affine Transformation Matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-454312) functions with the [Modifying Affine Transformations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000946-CH1g-TPXREF118) functions.

Comment: There is something wrong with your first code but the second works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HenryHarris It's because that method `CGAffineTransformRotation` should have been `CGAffineTransformRotate`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`CGAffineTransformMake` are applied to the identity matrix, so you are rotating, but then is like you restore the identity and apply the scale. Use `CGAffineTransformMake`.. only for the first, for the second use `CGAffineTransform`...